# No output when running Query using Java and Google's Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a program which is an event creator/locator. The problem I am having is pulling a query from the database. With this instance, I am just trying to pull a specific zip code from the database and display details of the appropriate document provided from the query.

```
private void findEvent() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Start FindEvent Function");
    eventRef.whereEqualTo("zip", searchZip.toString())
         .limit(1).get()
         .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                     Log.d(TAG, "Task Successful! Starting For Loop!");
                     for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                         Log.d(TAG, document.getId()+"=>"+document.getData());
                         updateUI(document);
                     }
                 } else {
                  Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                 }
             }
         });
}//end findEvent function
```

When I run the program, on my phone and hit the search button which starts the function above, nothing is outputted to my activity. I check the logs, which is the reason I put them in, and in the log, I get the Debug: "Task Successful! Starting for loop!" and then nothing after this when I am expecting a Debug log that I have in the updateUI function which tells me the function is starting. Therefore telling me that it is not running the updateUI function.

Comment: If you put a log statement in the `for` loop, does it show too? If it does, the problem is not related to retrieving data from the database. In that case, it must be somewhere in your `updateUI` method.

Comment: Does this line of code `Log.d(TAG, document.getId()+"=>"+document.getData());` print something?

Comment: As mentioned by Alex, there is a log that is within the for loop, and there is nothing printed from that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is probably just not returning any results, and your code is not checking for that case.

Before iterating the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) delivered to the task:

```
QuerySnapshot qsnapshot = task.getResult();
```

You could use its [isEmpty()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot.html#isEmpty()) method to determine if it actually contains any documents:

```
if (qsnapshot.isEmpty()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Query resulted in no documents");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think to do this. I have it added in now and know now why the loop wasn't executing. There was no result. So now that makes me wonder why. When I run the search I am looking right at the database as I type it into the search bar and still coming up with a blank. I looked at my code of how it is being saved and it converts it to a string and also when the search is conducted it converts it to a string so it is comparing string for string. I just don't understand how it can be exact and still no result...